# Find All HREF with specific class name with domdocument

Tags: php, dom

Assuming that a web page has a bunch of hrefs with various class names, as in

```
<a href="http://example.com/redlink1"   class="red">link </a>
<a href="http://example.com/bluelink2"  class="blue">link </a>
<a href="http://example.com/greenlink3" class="green">link </a>
<a href="http://example.com/redlink4"   class="red">link </a>
<a href="http://example.com/bluelink5"  class="blue">link </a>
<a href="http://example.com/greenlink6" class="green">link </a>
```

and I have loaded the page html into a dom.document.

I can extract all "A" tags with this loop, and then display the HREF value

```
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
    // Show the <a href>
    echo $link->getAttribute('href') . "<br>";
}
```

But how do I get only those HREF links that have a class name of 'blue'? This doesn't work inside the FOREACH:

```
$blue_class_links[] = $link->getElementByClass('blue');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `getAttribute('class')` to get the class.

```
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
    if ($link->getAttribute('class') == "blue") {
        echo $link->getAttribute('href') . "<br>";
    }
}
```

If it can have multiple classes, you'll need to split it up and search.

```
if (in_array("blue", explode(' ', $link->getAttribute('class'))))
```

If you know XPath there should be a way to write an expression that matches both the tag and class at once, but I've never bothered to learn XPath.

Comment: Thanks. I figured I was close. Upvoted both answers, but you got the green checkmark because of the added value of the code for multiple classes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the class is exactly blue (and not `class="blue some-other-class"` you can use the `getAttribute` method of the `$link` to check if the class equals blue:

```
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
    // Show the <a href>
    if ($link->getAttribute("class") == "blue") {
        echo $link->getAttribute('href') . "<br>";
    }
}
```